# Intellij cannot fetch an external resource

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, dtd

Intellij fails to fetch the external resource below:

http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-display_6_2_0.dtd

[image: Red error text]

When I use `Alt + Enter` to fetch resource, nothing happens. I'm not using a proxy or VPN and I can access/download the DTD in my browser.

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Intellij fixed the issue.